# How to implement a logger function as a child process in c?

Tags: c, process, fork

I've been struggling to implement a logger function in C that records when messages are written to a text file using communication via a pipe. In the simplified implementation below I'm trying to write messages from the parent process and print them from the child process without the file I/O but I don't ever get the child printfs.

In my `main` function, I spawn the logger by calling `spawn_logger` which forks a child process (`log_message`) that will run continuously. The parent process returns to the main, starts to send messages through the pipe, and finally kills the child process.

The `main` function:

```
int main(void){
    spawn_logger();
    char wmsg[] = "Greetings";
    send_message(wmsg);
    strcpy(wmsg, "Hello");
    send_message(wmsg);
    kill_child();

    return 0;
}
```

The `spawn_logger` function:

```
// global vars
pid_t pid;
int fd[2];

int spawn_logger() {
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        printf("Pipe failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { // fork error
        printf("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    if (pid > 0) { // parent process
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        return 0; // return to main
    }
    // child process
    // spawn the receiver process
    log_message();
    // the receiver process will never reach this point
    return 0;
}
```

The `send_message` function:

```
int send_message(char message[]){
    // do something with the message
    // e.g. write in a file
    printf("Message by parent sent: %s \n", message);

    // write the message to logger process
    int n = strlen(message) + 1;
    write(fd[WRITE_END], &n, sizeof(int));
    write(fd[WRITE_END], &message, sizeof(char) * strlen(message));

    return 0;
}
```

The `log_message` and `kill_child` functions:

```
// global vars
extern pid_t pid;
extern int fd[2];


int log_message(){
    //child process
    // will read from the pipe every time the parent process writes to it
    close(fd[WRITE_END]);

    int n;
    char *message;

    // read messages until parent process closes the pipe
    while (read(fd[READ_END], &n, sizeof(int)) > 0) {
        message = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
        read(fd[READ_END], &message, sizeof(char) * n);
        printf("Message by logger received: %s \n", message);
    }

    close(fd[READ_END]);
    exit(0);
}


int kill_child(){
    close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program all I get are the print messages `printf("Message by parent sent: %s \n", message);` and I think the problem comes from `log_message`.

I thought the child process would remain stuck in the while loop trying to read the buffer as long as the parent's write end is open but while debugging the child process in Clion I noticed that once it reaches the first line the program just stops. When I debug the parent process it just goes over all the writing instructions without any `broken pipe` errors.

How can I fix that? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your code won't work if `(strlen(msg) + 1) > PIPE_BUF`.  You're not guaranteed to get the full `read()` of the message in that case.  You also have another problem that won't be apparent unless your logger is used in a multithreaded application:  using two `write()` calls to the pipe won't be atomic.  You *might* be able to use [`writev()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html) to coalesce the length and message into a single atomic `write()` call, but note that's not explicitly guaranteed to be atomic. You might have to copy everything into a single buffer.

Comment: (cont) If you expand your  code to `void log_message( const char *fmt, ... )` to accept `printf()`-style arguments, you could create something like `struct logMsgStruct { uint16_t len; char[ PIPE_BUF - sizeof( uint16_t ); }` and then use `vsnprintf()` to create the log message, putting the length of the string + 1 in the `len` field.  Note you only need a `uint16_t` to count up to `PIPE_BUF - 2` bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After solving the issues pointed out by by andrew-henle and some-programmer-dude, I found the following solution to work the best.

```
int log_message(){ //child process

    close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char message[BUFSIZ];

    FILE * log;
    log = fopen("gateway.log", "a");

    // read is looping over every byte in the pipe
    // and is a blocking call until there's something to read
    // or the pipe is closed
    while(read( fd[READ_END], buffer, BUFSIZ) > 0 ) {
        int j = 0;
        memset(message, ' ', BUFSIZ); // make sure its empty
        // look for null terminator in buffer
        for(int i= 0; i < BUFSIZ; i++){
            // copy every byte until the null terminator
            message[i-j] = buffer[i];
            if(buffer[i] == '\0'){
                if(message[0] != '\0'){
                    printf("Message by logger received: %s \n", message);
                }
                buffer[i] = ' ';
                // reset j such that i - j is 0 for the next char of the buffer
                j = i + 1;
            }
        }
        memset(message, ' ', BUFSIZ); // clear message
    }
    fclose(log); // for now, we'll open and close the log file every time
    close(fd[READ_END]);
    kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't send the null-terminator.

***But*** the value of `n` includes the null-terminator.

This means that the child process will wait forever for the null-terminator that never comes.

---

There's an even worse problem: You use `&message` when sending the message.

This is worse, because `message` is not the array but a *pointer* to the first character of the array. So `&message` is a pointer *to the pointer*. So you write the pointer itself, plus some indeterminate data.

Drop the pointer-to operator `&` from that call to `write`:

```
write(fd[WRITE_END], message, n);
```

Note that I also updated the above to send the null-terminator.

Comment: Do you mean I need to concatenate the null terminator to `n` in `write(fd[WRITE_END], &n, sizeof(int));`?

Comment: @curioso You already have `int n = strlen(message) + 1;` which includes the null-terminator. But then you send `strlen(message)` bytes which does *not* include the terminator. You should send **`n`** bytes.